# SourceTree not working after Windows 10 Fall Creators Update

Tags: windows-10, atlassian-sourcetree

After install Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, sourcetree stop working.
When I try to open nothing happens.

I've already try to reinstall but no success.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was a bug! 
Affects Version/s: 2.2.4.0, 2.3.1.0

They released version 2.3.5.0 which includes a fix for this issue.
You can download it here: https://downloads.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/windows/ga/SourceTreeSetup-2.3.5.0.exe

Comment: I never needed to login to SourceTree and now forces me to do so. Why? What credentials should I use?